# Can I legally buy a car in Texas, but register it in California?

Tags: california, texas

I've got a quick question regarding vehicle registration in the States of California and Texas. I'm a full-time student at a public university in Texas, but am and remain a legal resident of the State of California. I'm looking to buy a new car, but I'd rather not have to buy the vehicle in California, and then make the drive to Texas. From my understanding, Texas law (according to the Texas DMV) provides exemptions for full-time students studying at an institution of higher education, so that they are not legally required to register their vehicle with the State of Texas. I've been able to find less information for California, with the only substantial information that I've been able to find that for an out-of-state vehicle to be registered in California, the vehicle must meet California's stricter emission regulations. But the question still stands, can I, as a legal resident of California, but studying in the State of Texas, purchase a vehicle in the State of Texas, and register the vehicle in the State of California?

Comment: if it's an older car, it would need a California smog check and you'll need to pay the California county sales tax.

Comment: Well, technically (european here ,but I did buy cars in other countries) there COULD be temporary transport permits fo a week, to drive to Californa. And there is always the possibility to NOT register it but put it on a truck and transport it to the place it gets registered. How you think new vehicles get to their owners without being registered?

Comment: @TomTom I believe you misunderstand, I don't want to have to take it back to California to register it. I want to be able to use it here in Texas.